# CollectionPager Problem With UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, pager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CollectionPager Problem With UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173465/collectionpager-problem-with-updatepanel)

I have a problem with collectionpager and repeater. When I load the page, collectionpager is working fine.. But I click the search button and binding new data and click the page 2 it is going the page_load and bring the all data again... Notice: All controls ara int UpdatePanel

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        kayit_getir("SELECT Tbl_Icerikler.ID,Tbl_Icerikler.url,Tbl_Icerikler.durum,Tbl_Icerikler.baslik,Tbl_Icerikler.gunc_tarihi,Tbl_Icerikler.kayit_tarihi,Tbl_Icerikler.sira,Tbl_Kategoriler.kategori_adi FROM Tbl_Icerikler,Tbl_Kategoriler where Tbl_Kategoriler.ID=Tbl_Icerikler.kategori_id ORDER BY Tbl_Icerikler.ID DESC,Tbl_Icerikler.sira ASC");
    }
}



public void kayit_getir(string SQL)
{
    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(f.baglan());
    baglanti.Open();
    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(SQL, baglanti);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(komut);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        CollectionPager1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
        CollectionPager1.BindToControl = Liste;
        Liste.DataSource = CollectionPager1.DataSourcePaged;
    }
    else
    {
       kayit_yok.Text = "<br /><span class='message information'>Kayıt bulunamadı.</span>";
    }
    da.Dispose();
    baglanti.Close();
    CollectionPager1.DataBind();
    Liste.DataBind();
}

protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string adi = f.temizle(baslik.Text);
    string durum = Durum.SelectedValue;
    string kayit_bas_t = kayit_bas_tarih.Text;
    string kayit_bit_t = kayit_bit_tarih.Text;
    string kategori = kategori_adi.SelectedValue;


    string SQL = "SELECT Tbl_Icerikler.ID,Tbl_Icerikler.url,Tbl_Icerikler.durum,Tbl_Icerikler.baslik,Tbl_Icerikler.gunc_tarihi,Tbl_Icerikler.kayit_tarihi,Tbl_Icerikler.sira,Tbl_Kategoriler.kategori_adi FROM Tbl_Icerikler,Tbl_Kategoriler where Tbl_Kategoriler.ID=Tbl_Icerikler.kategori_id and";
    if (adi != "")
    {
        SQL = SQL + " Tbl_Icerikler.baslik LIKE '%" + adi + "%' and";
    }

    if (kategori != "")
    {
        SQL = SQL + " Tbl_Icerikler.kategori_id=" + kategori + " and";
    }

    if (durum != "")
    {
        SQL = SQL + " Tbl_Icerikler.durum='" + durum + "' and";
    }

    if (kayit_bas_t != "")
    {
        SQL = SQL + " (Tbl_Icerikler.kayit_tarihi>'" + kayit_bas_t + "') and";
    }

    if (kayit_bit_t != "")
    {
        SQL = SQL + " (Tbl_Icerikler.kayit_tarihi<'" + kayit_bit_t + "') and";
    }

    SQL = SQL.Remove(SQL.Length - 3, 3);
    SQL = SQL + " ORDER BY sira ASC,ID DESC";

    try
    {
        kayit_getir(SQL);
    }
    catch { }
    Recursive(0, 0);
}
```

when I click the search button and click the pager button 2 it brings all data..